# Django app deploy on Heroku with DEBUG=False Server Error 500

Tags: django, heroku, deployment

I have an app deployed to Heroku. It runs fine both locally and on Heroku with "DEBUG = True". However, when I run it on Heroku with "DEBUG=False" I get a Server Error 500 like so:

```
2017-05-20T22:00:26.864342+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/plans/planslist/" host=app.mysite.com request_id=b9a4de90-4a81-42ff-b936-59aa3d17e02e fwd="50.181.204.79" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=443ms status=500 bytes=253 protocol=http
2017-05-20T22:00:27.304092+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=app.mysite.com request_id=b24922e4-974a-45db-8ce0-def179602203 fwd="50.181.204.79" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=57ms status=500 bytes=239 protocol=http
```

I must have a setting wrong but cannot figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've hacking on this for half the day and have gotten no where.

My settings.py

```
import os
from django.conf import settings
from .base import *

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False

import dj_database_url
DATABASES = { 'default': dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500) }

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['app.mysite.com']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'bootstrap3',
    'company_account',
    'company_data',
    'plans',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'registration',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ]

# Usual Middleware here

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mywebapp.wsgi.application'

STATIC_URL = '/collectstatic/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'

# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    )

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

Comment: try setting your allowed hosts like this:  `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.mysite.com']`

Comment: @KostasLivieratos Tried that but it did not help.

Comment: do you have any logging service? That would help to get the error traceback

Answer (score 0):

Server error (500) when trying to deploy Django app with DEBUG=False on Heroku can be resolved by installing

> pip install whitenoise

Edit your `settings.py` file and add WhiteNoise to the MIDDLEWARE list, above all other middleware apart from Django’s SecurityMiddleware:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
  # 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
  'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
  # ...
]
```

If you install `django-heroku`, try to comment it out and also comment `django_heroku.settings(locals())` out.

You can turn your `DEBUG = False` and redeploy to Heroku.
This method actually worked for me. You can give it a try.

You can also read `whitenoise` documentation: http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/